# Better gem for MongoDB

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Given the size of my database and queries I have decided to shift to NoSQL database MongoDb. Are there any gem for using MondoDb with Rails 3. Also, which gem is better?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center says how to get the driver, why don't you start there?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [official driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center) and to improve performance I'd advise also installing the bson_ext gem as its faster than the native ruby one.

I'm not 100% clear on what the issue is - size or speed. If its speed then make sure you do due diligence and test your dataset before migrating.  The [MongoDB user group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user) is a great place to get feedback on schema design and appropriate use cases for MongoDB - Its not a panacea and not all use cases are appropriate.

Size wise you are likely to use more space. Data is stored in [bson](http://bsonspec.org/) - a compressed Binary Json format, but as MongoDB is schemaless you cant get the size optimizations that a RDMS can provide, for example field names are stored only once in MySQL whereas MongoDB has to store them in each document. Indexes will also increase the size stored on disk and MongoDB also does [data preallocation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation) to improve performance which takes up space as well.

For integration with Rails check out the [wiki](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started)

Hope that helps.